# Oracle-Form assign value to user-defined type

Tags: sql, forms, oracle

I'm creating an (stored) user-defined type on database level:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Some_Text AS VARRAY(20) OF VARCHAR2(50);
```

Then there is a (stored) procedure that using this user-defined type:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Test_Procedure(
     p_to IN Some_Text,
     p_from IN Some_Text

 --some code here--
 )
```

On form-level (Form Builder), I created a datablock with tabular (5 text-items). 
On this text-item user can enter some text. Then this text will be used as parameter when calling procedure "Test_Procedure". How to do that?
I could call the procedure with this code:

```
 Test_Procedure
            (Some_Text('bla', 'bla', 'bla'),
             Some_Text('bla', 'bla', 'bla'));
```

But, I don't know how to do that with datablock.text-item.

Note:
I'm still very new to oracle, so please bear with me.
Thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the block to construct the varray.

Ex.

```
declare
  i number := 0
begin
  go_block('myblock');
  first_record;
  loop
    exit when :system.last_record = 'TRUE';
    i := i + 1;
    some_text(i) := :myblock.mytextitem;
    next_record;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: It give an error. I figure out that form can't access user-defined type on schema level. So, I put the type and procedure on a package. It solved now using your method. Thanks.